# Best way of separating angular frontend and admin section

Tags: angular, angular5

I am building my first Angular 5 app where we would have a frontend section and an admin section. What would be the best way to achieve this. The 2 ways I can think of are:

1. Building separate angular projects for frontend and admin section
   which would be accessing the same API and database
2. Separating one angular project in Modules for Frontend and Admin. But the issue with this would be that there would be separate modules in the frontend module itself.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go with the 2nd option, You should have a separate Module built in for Admin section with lazy loading implemented.

Having separate Modules in the SPA is common.

Answer (score 0):

Admin section, like other sections, is a part of the website. You can build the admin section in the same project. 
The modules that admin requires can be loaded lazily, whenever required.

Now how to implement lazy loading-

[Angularfirebase tutorials video and step by step implementation](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/how-to-lazy-load-components-in-angular-4-in-three-steps/)

[Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)